# Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: function signature mismatch when using Tesseract.js

Tags: javascript

Have run into what I suspect is a problem with the async function. The error thrown is: Uncaught (in promise) RuntimeError: function signature mismatch
when I'm trying to have my image run through OCR using tesseract.js
Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? Is it the way I've constructed my async function?

This is the relevant snippet. It's indicating that the last line is causing the error

```
const { createWorker } = require('tesseract.js');

const worker = createWorker();
generateText = () => {
      let uploads = this.state.uploads;
      console.log(uploads);

      for(var i = 0; i < uploads.length; i++) {


        (async () => {
          await worker.load();
          await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
          await worker.initialize('eng');
          const { data: { text } } = await worker.recognize(uploads[i]);
          console.log(text);
          await worker.terminate();
        })();
 }
    }
```

Comment: I don't know Tesseract, but I get a bad smell reusing the worker the way you have it now. Do you mean to do each upload in sequence? If so, I think you want to save the promise from the first async call, then use `.then`, and save that promise, etc. Let me know if that doesn't make sense

Comment: Alternatively (again assuming you want to do each upload in sequence), make the outer function async, and await your original async function in the for loop body. Probably cleaner if generateText can be async in its usage

Answer (score 1):

Update the library, that error occurs in version 2.1.1 and version 2.1.2 no longer comes out

https://cdnjs.com/libraries/tesseract.js/2.1.2

Comment: I'm using tesseract.js 2.1.5 and still got it. I think we need to handle the error with some method like try catch and prevent using throw error.